# i want to reduce products quantity after an order delivered laravel 7

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-7

**so This is the button that i confirm that a order is delivered**

```
@elseif($order->order_status == 'Confirmed')
        <div >
          <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('updateorderstatus',['order'=>$order->id])}}" method="post" >
           @csrf
<input  name="order_id" type="hidden" value="{{$order->id}}"/>
          <input name="order_status" type="hidden" value="Shipping"/>
              <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
        <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
        <i class="fa fa-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>

        </button>
       </a>
     </form>
     </div>
@elseif( $order->order_status == 'Shipping'  )
                                    <div   class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
                                        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{route('updateorderstatus')}}" method="post" >
                                            @csrf
                                            <input  name="order_id" type="hidden" value="{{$order->id}}"/>
                                            <input name="order_status" type="hidden" value="Delivered"/>
                                            <input  name="quantity" type="hidden" value="{{$order->quantity}}"/>
                                            <input  name="product_id" type="hidden" value="{{$order->product_id}}"/>
                                            <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
                                                <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-check-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                                </button>
                                            </a>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
```

**the function that update order status and i try to reduce quantity**

```
public function updateorderstatus(Request $request)

{
    $order = Order::all();
    if ($request->isMethod('post')  ){

            $data = $request->all();

            Order::where('id',$data['order_id'])->update(['order_status'=>$data['order_status']]);


             $current = Order::where('order_status','Delivered')->get();

              Dvproduct::where('product_id',$data['product_id'])->update( ['quantity'=>$current - $data['quantity']] );


    }


    return back();
```

}

and i got 2 errors

when i click on the first button i get `Undefined index: product_id`

and when i click on the second `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection could not be converted to number`

Comment: The first error you are facing because in both forms you have a post method so your if condition will be true in both forms. And in one form you have product_id but in other form you don't have thats why you are facing this error.

Comment: so i have to add input product_id to other form

Comment: It depends on your forms and logic ? If you have multiple forms then you have to handle it with your own thinking, like how you want your forms to be.

Comment: update order status is just to update the order of status by id , its working fine , 2 last lines in the function i just add them trying reduce the quantity when the status ='delivered' should i make other function for delivered form ??

Comment: what are you trying to get from order table ? is there any field to be sum ? like $current should be what value ? And yes you have to make another function for delivered order.

Comment: where status is delivered and product_id is the same $data['product_id'] that i get in form

Comment: what value you want to be in `$current` variable from order table?

Comment: the quantity shoul i add it insitde get ()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214198/discussion-between-akhtar-munir-and-yassine-haidas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here is little correction, also try to make another function and route for ordered button

Change

```
$current = Order::where('order_status','Delivered')->get();
```

To

```
$current = Order::where('order_status','Delivered')->sum('quantity');
```

Now this will work

```
Dvproduct::where('product_id',$data['product_id'])->update( ['quantity'=>$current - $data['quantity']] );
```